# How to use database views in EF Core 3.0?

Tags: ef-core-3.0

I know the question was asked before, but at the time it was, we had EF Core 2.x. The short answer was "no you can't" and obviously, not very helpful.

The other answers involved ugly hacks like changing migration files after they were created by the tool.

I make an application Code First. I have my models created with lot's of foreign keys and database joins in mind.

But here comes the unpleasant surprise (I'm a little new to EF): those joins written in LINQ are pretty slow, as a matter of fact they do not produce database join, but fetch whole tables instead.

Of course it's totally unacceptable, I import an old database with millions of records, with the joins I get results in milliseconds, without I get couple of seconds lags - on my very fast internet connection (in real world scenario it would be much worse).

I need views, and AFAIK EF won't create them for me, is it STILL true for EF 3.0?

Then, what would be the best and the most clean way to create views in SQL and to make entities for them? I mean - considering the situation the database models would change over time, and the database structure would have to be updated.

Well, I would prefer doing my joins not in SQL views, just have queries returned "JOIN" statement results. Especially some not obvious joins. Lets say table B has a column being a foreign key referencing table A. I want to get results from table A joining B for details. With normal SQL JOIN performance.

I checked the database: there is no significant performance difference between "select * from A" and "select * from A join B...". In LINQ - the difference is huge.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in Code First database views are redundant.
The "views" can be created as models (ordinary classes) having a field or a property set to joined entity. I use private fields for that purpose. Then I use `LINQ` `Join()` to create my view entity. The query may refer ONLY to the fields set to joined entities, nothing else. Such query, if written properly translates clearly to `SQL` `JOIN` and works with full speed. In my application it's equivalent of a database view.

Why private fields and not properties, you may ask. Maybe because joined entities are "implementation details", but another reason is my presentation code uses reflection to operate on entity public properties, it's good to have those entities hidden from it. Otherwise I would probably need to use attributes to hide those "columns".

BTW, such views can be ordered with `OrderBy()`, filtered with `Where()` at virtually no cost. The constraint is to maintain the collection's `IQueryable` interface, never refer joined entities indirectly. So even if `X` refers to `A.B`, never refer `X` in a `LINQ` query, always `A.B` where A is direct entity reference assigned in the `Join()` query.

To build dynamic queries at runtime one must use expressions.

This set of properties of EF Core 3.0 allows to build a database application without using SQL, but with the full SQL speed maintained. However, the database / entity structure must be relatively simple to achieve that.